# Does codemirror provide Cut, Copy and Paste API?

Tags: codemirror

From http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html, I only find `getRange()`,
undo(), redo() etc, and I can't find cut(), copy() and paste API,
and more when I try to run `editor.execCommand("cut")`, I get the error.
Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929371/copy-and-paste-in-codemirror-js-embeded-in-javafx-application

Answer (score 14):

Using [***clipboard.js***](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/), you can define the `text()` function to grab the value of the CodeMirror's inner document.

Store a reference to the (`<textarea>`) editor's selector for convenience.

```js
var editorSelector = '#editor' // or '#editor + .CodeMirror';
```

Instantiate a new `ClipBoard` object with reference to your button.

```js
new Clipboard('.clip-btn-native', {
    text: function(trigger) {
        return getCodeMirrorNative(editorSelector).getDoc().getValue();
    }
});
```

Retrieve a `CodeMirror` Instance via native JavaScript.

```js
function getCodeMirrorNative(target) {
    var _target = target;
    if (typeof _target === 'string') {
        _target = document.querySelector(_target);
    }
    if (_target === null || !_target.tagName === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Element does not reference a CodeMirror instance.');
    }

    if (_target.className.indexOf('CodeMirror') > -1) {
        return _target.CodeMirror;
    }

    if (_target.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') {
        return _target.nextSibling.CodeMirror;
    }

    return null;
};
```

---

## Demo

Please see complete; in-depth demo over at [***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/3phdkg66/).

Comment: Is it possible to also copy the markup/css style with it, so my nice colored syntax highlighted code gets preserved when copying for example to Word?

Comment: @Jan That would be a RTF (rich-text format) copy. I am not sure if it supports it at the moment. This example uses clipboard.js AND CodeMirror, so the formatting used by CodeMirror is a layer above this copying mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

There are no CodeMirror APIs for cut/copy/paste because browser security restrictions forbid JavaScript from accessing the clipboard programmatically. Paste could be used to steal private data and Cut/Copy can be used as a [more elaborate attack vector](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-10021715-83.html).

The browser's own native code handles *user* gestures that access the clipboard (keyboard shortcuts and context menu items), based solely on the currently selected text or focused text field.

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658282/javascript-cut-copy-paste-to-clipboard-how-did-google-solve-it) has a good summary of attempts to work around these restrictions. CodeMirror's approach is the first bullet: it uses a hidden textarea to ensure that user clipboard gestures work, but that still doesn't support programmatic APIs.

But there *is* a partial workaround: use a small Flash widget (this is the 2nd bullet in the thread above). Flash [relaxes the restrictions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html) on Copy/Cut (but not Paste) a bit. It still has to be triggered by *some* user event, but it could be something like clicking a button in your HTML UI. Wrappers like [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) and [Clippy](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy) make it simple to access to these capabilities without needing to know Flash. You'd need to write a little glue code to pull the appropriate string from CodeMirror when copying, but it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Unfortunately, CodeMirror does not seem to interoperate well with Android/Chrome. Specifically, the long-tap to select does not work, so it isn't possible to copy text.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden contenteditable div to your textarea editor wrapper. Contenteditable divs respect new lines and tabs, which we need when copying code.

Here is my [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/ZEzWjyg)

```js
var content = $('.content');
var toCopy = content.find('.copy-this');
// initialize the editor
var editorOptions = {
  autoRefresh: true,
  firstLineNumber: 1,
  lineNumbers: true,
  smartIndent: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  indentWithTabs: true,
  refresh: true,
  mode: 'javascript'
};
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(content.find(".editor")[0], editorOptions);
content[0].editor = editor;
editor.save();

// set editors value from the textarea
var text = content.find('.editor').text();
editor.setValue(text);

// setting with editor.getValue() so that it respects \n and \t
toCopy.text(editor.getValue());

$(document).on('click', '.copy-code', function() {
  var content = $(this).closest('.content');
  var editor = content[0].editor;
  var toCopy = content.find('.copy-this')[0];

  var innerText = toCopy.innerText  // using innerText here because it preserves newlines

  // write the text to the clipboard
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(innerText);

});
```

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.CodeMirror {
  height: fit-content !important;
}
.copy-code {
  background: #339af0;
  width: fit-content;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- resources -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.35.0/codemirror.css" />
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.40.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>
<script src=""></script>
<script src=""></script>
<script src=""></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="content">
  <!-- button to copy the editor -->
  <div class="copy-code" title="copy code">copy</div>
  <!-- add contenteditable div as it respects new lines when copying unlike textarea -->
  <div class="copy-this" contenteditable style="display: none"></div>
  <textarea class="editor" style="display: none;">// here is a comment
// here is another comment 
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: @nourza Thanks, looks like the clipboard api has been blocked here. `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document.`