# CodeMirror2: How to format a pasted content?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Is it possible to format the inserted content after an event like "onPaste" in CodeMirror2? - I want to indent the content from the clipboard after pasting. I already know with JavaScript it's not possible to get access to the clipboard.

So I think there is also no possiblity to create a context menu with cut/copy/paste functions? - Could I create my own JS-clipboard or is there an existing solution?

Thanks!
leX

Answer (score 4):

Took me a little while to work this out, so in case it helps anyone, here's how I'm intercepting pastes and replacing each tab with 2 spaces:

```js
editor.on("beforeChange", (cm, change) => {
  if(change.origin === "paste") {
    const newText = change.text.map(line => line.replace(/\t/g, "  "));
    change.update(null, null, newText);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A CodeMirror has native "inputRead" event so you can do this:

```
editor.on('inputRead', function(cm, event) {
    /* event -> object{
         origin: string, can be '+input', '+move' or 'paste'
             doc for origins >> http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#selection_origin
         from: object {line, ch},
         to: object {line, ch},
         removed: array of removed strings
         text: array of pasted strings
    } */
    if (event.origin == 'paste') {
        console.log(event.text);
        var text = event.text[0]; // pasted string
        var new_text = '['+text+']'; // any operations here
        cm.refresh();
        // my first idea was
        // note: for multiline strings may need more complex calculations
        cm.replaceRange(new_text, event.from, {line: event.from.line, ch: event.from.ch + text.length});
        // first solution did'nt work (before i guess to call refresh) so i tried that way, works too
        /* cm.execCommand('undo');
        cm.setCursor(event.from);
        cm.replaceSelection(new_text); */
    }
});
```

And there are also other events "cut", "copy" and "paste" (http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events) so this will work:

```
editor.on('paste', function(cm, event) { ... } );
```

Andavtage is you can cancel event by calling event.preventDefault(); but retrieving pasted text is a problem.

Currently i am working on similar thing - hook copy/paste events and make some replacements. I found a solution to programmatically copy text to clipboard. This is [clipboard.js](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/)
discussed here [Does codemirror provide Cut, Copy and Paste API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492842/does-codemirror-provide-cut-copy-and-paste-api). The great thing is you can trigger click event programmatically (that was a problem when i used ZeroClipboard with cross-browser flash shim) and it will work!

```
new Clipboard('.btn-copy', {
    text: function(trigger) {
        var text = editor.getValue(); // or editor.getSelection();
        return text.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
    }
});

editor.on('copy', function(cm, event) {
    $('.btn-copy').click();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found was intercepting the even using `inputRead` and then manually changing the pasted contents. I made a generic funcion you could reuse:

```
class CodeMirrorExt {
    // This function returns a callback to be used with codemirror's inputRead event.
    // The intent is to intercept a pasted text, transform the pasted contents (each line) with the function
    // you provide, and then have that transformed content be what ends up in the editor.
    //
    // Usage example that cuts each pasted line to 10 chars:
    //
    // this.codemirror.on("inputRead", CodeMirrorExt.replaceTextOnPasteFunc((line) => {
    //     return line.slice(0, 10);
    // }));

    static replaceTextOnPasteFunc(transformFunc) {
        return ((doc, event) => {
            if (event.origin !== "paste") {
                return;
            }

            const firstText = event.text[0];
            const lineNum = event.from.line;
            const chNum = event.from.ch;

            const newTexts = event.text.map(transformFunc);

            newTexts.forEach((text, i) => {
                if (i == 0) {
                    doc.replaceRange(text, {line: lineNum, ch: chNum}, {line: lineNum, ch: chNum + firstText.length});
                }
                else {
                    doc.replaceRange(text, {line: lineNum + i, ch: 0}, {line: lineNum + i, ch: event.text[i].length});
                }
            })
        });
    }
}

export default CodeMirrorExt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) you can beautify the editors value during a `paste` event on the `.CodeMirror` like so:

```
$(document).on('paste', '.CodeMirror', function(e) {
    var content = $(this).closest('.content');
    var editor = content[0].editor;

    // beautify the code
    editor.setValue( js_beautify( editor.getValue(), { indent_size: 2 } ) );
});
```

Be aware that when inserting text into the editor, it listens to the first indentation, so if your first line is indented, all other lines will be indented accordingly.

**ex:**

```
    function something() { // if the start is indented like so,
        var blah = something; // next lines will follow
    }
```