# Function Undefined error in JavaFX application

Tags: jquery, json, copy-paste

The requirement was to embed a JSON editor in a javafx application. I tried embedding the json editor(powered by Ace) https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor into my javafx application with the help of webview. Everything is working except copy(CTRL+C) and paste(CTRL+V).

After a research, I came to know that javafx webkit is of **safari**. But I tried the same editor in web browsers like firefox, chrome and all. Even in latest version of safari it is working well, but I failed to get it working in javafx webview.
Currently I am using the latest JDK(8), so having the latest javafx also.
Is there any way by which I can get the copy paste shortcut keys to be working on my embedded editor in javafx webview?
Please help.

Comment: i am new to jquery, but i think, some jquery libraries may help you in the custom copy paste implementations.

Answer (score 7):

ace.js uses the clipboard, and in any regular browser it works fine, but inside a JavaFX webView, there's a problem. If you look for the function `handleClipboardData` in ace.js you can see that:

- Copy works internally, but when it tries to `setData` it fails.
- Paste doesn't work because `getData` fails.

Looking for a workaround I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929371/copy-and-paste-in-codemirror-js-embeded-in-javafx-application) related to codemirror, that could be applied to ace.js as well.

Basically, you have to make a bridge in your JavaFX application (outside the ace editor) to deal with copy and paste events. Something like this:

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    webView=new WebView();
    webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    webEngine.load(Utils.class.getResource("editor.html").toExternalForm());

    // Capture Ctrl+V event and process it
    webView.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
        if (keyEvent.isControlDown() && keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.V){
            // PASTE
            final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
            String content = (String) clipboard.getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT);
            webEngine.executeScript(" pasteContent(\""+content+"\") ");

        }
    });

    // retrieve copy event via javascript:alert
    webEngine.setOnAlert((WebEvent<String> we) -> {
        if(we.getData()!=null && we.getData().startsWith("copy: ")){
               // COPY
               final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
               final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
               content.putString(we.getData().substring(6));
               clipboard.setContent(content);    
        }
    });
}
```

Now in editor.html,you have to create the `pasteContent` function that will be called from the webEngine on a paste event:

```
<script>
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
...
function pasteContent(content){
    editor.onPaste(content);
}
</script>
```

And finally in ace.js, in the function `getCopyText`, close to line 13071, you have to insert the alert, so the copied text in the editor can be sent to the webEngine. Note the use of the hardcoded string `"copy: "`, for simplicity.

```
this.getCopyText = function() {
    var text = this.getSelectedText();
    javascript:alert("copy: "+text);
    this._signal("copy", text);
    return text;
};
```

This will be all.

Comment: Instead of editing the ace getCopyText method, a better option would be to receive an edit event from ace itself: editor.on('copy', handler)