# Cannot paste into ACE editor on JavaFX WebView

Tags: webview, javafx-8, clipboard, paste, ace-editor

I'm developing a small JavaFX application. I would like to embed a Lua editor. I'm using ACE Editor in my application through a WebView node. The editor loads perfectly; however, I cannot paste any text through mouse events and keyboard events, regardless from where the text was copied. Is this a known bug?

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Lua Editor</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #editor { 
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor"></div>
        <script src="ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script>
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/lua");
            editor.setOptions({
                fontSize: "11pt"
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java code snippet:

```
@FXML
private WebView scriptEditor;

private void initializeCardScript() {
    scriptEditor.getEngine().load("path to HTML file");
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25676561/3956070

Comment: Oh, ok thanks! I will do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With José Pereda suggestion, I was able to paste text through key events with ctrl+v. But I couldn't paste with the mouse click Copy/Cut/Paste dialog.

I was able to solve my problem entirely, by creating a communication bridge from Javascript to java. I call a java method on the paste event at ACE editor.

Java code snippet:

```
private void initializeCardScript() {
    scriptEditor.getEngine().load("path to HTML file");
    ((JSObject) scriptEditor.getEngine().executeScript("window")).setMember("java", new Object() {
        public void paste() {
            String content = (String) Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT);
            if (content != null) {
                scriptEditor.getEngine().executeScript("editor.onPaste(\"" + content.replace("\n", "\\n") + "\");");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

ace.js:

```
var onPaste = function(e) {
    java.paste();
//  var data = handleClipboardData(e);
//  if (typeof data == "string") {
//      if (data)
//          host.onPaste(data, e);
//      if (useragent.isIE)
//          setTimeout(resetSelection);
//      event.preventDefault(e);
//  }
//      else {
//          text.value = "";
//          pasted = true;
//      }
};
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25676561/3956070

https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx